# Como faço a consulta passada por get em pdo de id para codigo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou iniciando em pdo agora, então começarão os jogos pra mim a pouco e minha dúvida é a seguinte:
estou trabalhando em cima de outro código de um amigo e no código dele o get para exibir as informações são pegos os valores por id, porém eu quero que as informações sejam buscadas por outra coluna "codigo" e não consegui fazer essa alteração, podem me ajudar. O código é o seguinte:

```
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o id do cliente do cliente via GET
$id_cliente = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

// Valida se existe um id e se ele é numérico
if (!empty($id_cliente) && is_numeric($id_cliente)):

    // Captura os dados do cliente solicitado
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id, codigo, nome, cursos, data_inicio, data_termino, horas FROM tab_clientes WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':id', $id_cliente);
    $stm->execute();
    $cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

endif;
```

no url fica assim: http://localhost/rm/certificado/sistema/imprimir.php?id=1

porém deverá ficar assim: http://localhost/rm/certificado/sistema/imprimir.php?codigo=169fe1d7227

me ajudem ai por favor.

Comment: Qual o código que chama está página, do select?

Comment: Comece alterando `$_GET['id']` por `$_GET['codigo']`. O trecho: `if (!empty($id_cliente) && is_numeric($id_cliente)):` não condiz com o comentário. Use `filter_input` ao invés de pergar o valor via `$_GET` direto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que é isso que você quer:

```
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o codigo do cliente do cliente via GET
$codigo= (isset($_GET['codigo'])) ? $_GET['codigo'] : '';

//isset vai testar se existe "codigo" se existir ele retorna no 
//$_GET['codigo'] se nao retorna uma string vazia

if (!empty($codigo) && is_numeric($codigo)):
    //testando se o codigo é um numero válido, se a coluna codigo não for de 
    // números precisa alterar essa condição se não nunca vai entrar

    // Captura os dados do cliente solicitado
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    //no Where você manda filtrar os dados pela coluna codigo
    $sql = 'SELECT id, codigo, nome, cursos, data_inicio, data_termino, horas FROM tab_clientes WHERE codigo= :codigo LIMIT 1';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':codigo', $codigo);
    //Aqui ele subistitui a parte ":codigo" pelo valor na variavel $codigo
    $stm->execute();
    $cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

endif;
```